# How to score one dataframe with conditions?

Tags: python, dataframe, machine-learning, lambda

I split the dataframe into 2 segments, and built one model on each segment. how to score one dataframe with conditions (with different models)? Here is what I tried  -

Method 1 - works.  score each segment , then stack them up.

Method 2- lambda, not work, need help on this.

Please see sample code below.

```
d3=df[df['age']>=30].copy()
x3_train=d3[varlist]
y3_train=d3[target]

d4=df[df['age']<30].copy()
x4_train=d4[varlist]
y4_train=d4[target]

model_hi=XGBRegressor()
model_low=XGBRegressor()

model_hi.fit(x3_train, y3_train)
model_low.fit(x4_train, y4_train)

# method 1 -works 
d3['score']=model_hi.predict(d3[varlist])
d4['score']=model_low.predict(d4[varlist])

df= pd.concat([d3,d4]).reset_index(drop=True)

# method 2 - not work, need help 
df['score']=df.apply(lambda x: model_hi.predict(x[varlist]) if x['age']>=30 else model_low.predict(x[varlist]),axis=1)
```

Comment: What's the error you are getting in second method?